# re error in using gpiozero

Tags: python, gpiozero

I am new to RPi, though have lot of experience with Arduino.
I recently installed the 'gpiozero' module to my RPi system, and while trying to run a simple LED on-off file, I encounter an error...something like this....

```
Traceback (most recent call last ):
etc..etc..
File "user/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/pins/rpigpio.py", line 57, in RPI.GPIO.Pin 'pwm': GPIO.HARD_PWM, AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'HARD_PWM'
```

What does this mean? I am stuck up, what to do next, please help.

Comment: What's your script called. If it's gpiozero.py Rename it to my_gpiozero.py `mv gpiozero.py my_gpiozero.py` and remove any *.pyc files with `rm *.pyc`. Python always searches the current directory first for any scripts or imported scripts.

Comment: You have removed the useful information from the traceback.  If you put it back in it may be possible to give an answer.

Comment: What @joan said, plus it looks like either you named your file `RPi.py` or you have a broken installation of RPi.GPIO.

Comment: Many Thanks to all of you, will check with file name, removing the .pyc, and will give full feedback details again in the error included details in the traceback...

Comment: is there any quick way to confirm if installation of 'gpiozero' has been fully/completely done ? or I need to uninstall and install again ?

Comment: Hi Joan;The error massage in full is as follows

Comment: pi@raspberrypi ~ $  sudo python ledOnOff.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ledOnOff.py", line 1, in <module>
from gpiozero import LED
File " usr/Lib/python 2.7/dist-packages/gpiozero/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>

Comment: from .devices import (
File " usr/Lib/python 2.7/dist-packages/gpiozero/devices.py", line 38, in <module>
from .pins.rpigpio import RPiGPIOPin
File " usr/Lib/python 2.7/dist-packages/gpiozero/pins/rpigpio.py", line 27, in <module>
class RPiGPIOPin(Pin):
File " usr/Lib/python 2.7/dist-packages/gpiozero/pins/rpigpio.py", line 57, in RPiGPIOPin
'pwm':   GPIO.HARD_PWM,
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'HARD_PWM'
pi@raspberrypi ~ $

Comment: I used the file name as ledOnOff this time

Comment: I tried to remove the pyc files (using rm *.pyc command), but the reply I got is

Comment: rm: cannot remove '*.pyc ': No such file or directory

Comment: Now the last thing I need to check if my 'gpiozero' installation has been correctly done...but I do not know how to confirm the same ????